# QR code generation from an image?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I wish to know if a QR code can be generated from an image input, like how one can generate QR code from a text input. So that, when I scan the QR code, I should be able to get the image as the scan result.

Can someone please let me know if this is possible?

Comment: You'd have to make a really big QR code block, as the image contains *tons* of information.

Comment: Short answer - no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have to be either an incredibly small bitmap, or a link to the image hosted somewhere else.  The map of a QR code expands depending on data size, and while I am unsure if there is a technical upper limit, there is almost assuredly a practical upper limit with camera resolution being unable to decipher the massive code.